# IPSec on Windows: Is "Monitoring" node in Windows Firewall "good enough"?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ipsec

I'm on AWS EC2 and would like to understand how much additional CPU overhead we'll add by enabling IPSEC on our Windows machines inside a VPC

I have load / perf testing baselines from one of our primary apps.

I want to turn IPSec on, re-run the same load and perf tests, and watch to see if the transactions/sec we used to be able to drive go down significantly. Will also monitor CPU utilization, etc.

Anyway, NOT a networking guy and wouldn't be able to use wireshark if someone put a gun to my head. I've configured requisite IPSec Security Rules on my 2012 R2 boxes, and when I create connections between the machines included in the rules, I see information showing up under Monitoring / Firewall / Security / Main (Quick) Mode.

Is this a good enough signal that traffic between the machines is encrypted and I'm (perhaps) "paying a little extra" cost in CPU? Or do I really need to use wirehark, netmon, etc? Are there any fire-and-forget tools I could use to confirm without me having to capture frames and try and read traffic?

Bonus question: If I want to see a "worst case" scenario, should I just pick the the 256-bit algos rather than SHA-1 or MD5?

Thanks much.

Comment: I would wireshark it on one end or the other, just to be absolutely sure. As for cost, the extra CPU usage is pretty trivial on modern processors.

Comment: OK, OK. You shamed me into trying Wireshark. Not as bad as I thought it would be. When I examine the frames flying back and forth between the two servers I've setup IPSec on, I see an "Encapsulating Security Payload" entry with an ESP SPI and ESP Sequence value. Does that mean I'm good? :)

Comment: ESP is indeed encrypted IPsec traffic.